# While loop does not finish in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a problem with my queries at my MySQL database. I have to represent some variables in a graph.

So far I have

- JavaScript that reads what variables I have to represent and POST with Ajax
- PHP code to handle the POST

My PHP code has a POST function that does a query with inner joins depending if my variables are in the same table or not. This query obtains a table with datetime and all the variables. This POST function works well, I tested it.

The problem is when I want to represent more than 4 variables. If I want to represent 5 variables, I can represent less than 97,000 rows. If I want to represent 6 variables, I can represent less than 86,000 rows (each time I add a variable I lose around 11,000 rows).

**My javascript code**

```
jQuery.extend({
    llamada: function() {
        var result=null;
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            url:"includes/mysql.php",
            data: { tarea:'ejecutarQuery',
                table: varNames,
                columna: varLocations
            },
            success: function(respuesta){
                alert(respuesta);
                /*result=respuesta;*/
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
});
var myServerData = $.llamada();
```

**The post function in mysql.php**

```
if($_POST["tarea"]=="ejecutarQuery"){
    $columnas = $_POST["columna"];
    $tablas = $_POST["table"];
    $tablacolumna = array();
    $frasecolumnas="";
    for($j=0;$j<count($columnas);$j++){
      $tablacolumna[$j]=$tablas[$j].".".$columnas[$j];
      if($j==0){
        $frasecolumnas=$tablacolumna[0];
      }
      else{
        $frasecolumnas=$frasecolumnas.",".$tablacolumna[$j];
      }
    }
    $tablasdiferentes= array();
    $tablasdiferentes[0]=$tablas[0];
    $contador=0;
    for($j=1;$j<count($tablas);$j++){
      for($i=0;$i<count($tablasdiferentes);$i++){
        if($tablas[$j]==$tablasdiferentes[$i]){
          break 1;
        }
        if($i==$contador){
          $tablasdiferentes[$i+1]=$tablas[$j];
          $contador++;
        }
      }
    }
    $frasetablas="FROM ".$tablas[0]." ".$tablas[0]." ";
    $fraseError =" where ".$tablas[0].".ErrorBit=0";
    for($j=1;$j<count($tablasdiferentes);$j++){
      $frasetablas=$frasetablas."inner join ".$tablasdiferentes[$j]." ".$tablasdiferentes[$j]." on ".$tablas[0].".datetime=".$tablasdiferentes[$j].".datetime ";
      $fraseError =$fraseError." and ".$tablasdiferentes[$j].".ErrorBit = 0";
    }
    $sql="SELECT ".$tablas[0].".datetime,".$frasecolumnas." ".$frasetablas.$fraseError.";";
    $rawdata=getArraySQL($sql);
    echo json_encode($rawdata);  
  }
```

**method getArraySQL**

```
function getArraySQL($sql){
    $conexion = conectarBD();
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conexion);
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die(mysql_error);
    $rawdata = array();
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))
    {
      $time = $row[0];
      $date = new DateTime($time);
      $row[0] = $date->getTimestamp()*1000;
      $rawdata[$i] = $row;
      $i++;
    }
    desconectarBD($conexion);
    return $rawdata;
  }
```

I think that the problem may be that the while loop does not finish depending on the number of variables. I suppose it is because of the array's memory size.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: So what exactly doesnt work - when you request 5 or more variables, what happens?

Comment: When I request 5 variables, the console shows a 500 HTML error. I checked that the error is in method getArraySQL(). Then I checked that if I only want to represent 97,000 rows (In the while loop I put --> if($i<97000)...) it works. It seems that the while loop does not have capacity to load all the rows in $rawdata and it never ends.

Comment: OK, well then its probably a memory error - why do you want to return 100k results in one go?

Comment: It's not that I want to return 100k results in one go, I want to represent all the data in my table. My table has more than 100k results and every minute it grows with more rows (it is used to store real-time data). I want to represent every row in a graph but I don't know how to divide these data to avoid this memory error. Do you have any suggestions? It would be really appreciated. Thanks for your answers Steve!